# Magento 2: Create Custom Shipping Extension to Change Customer Group

Tags: magento2, customer, shipping, customer-group

I need to create new shipping method that also change price rules for the customer.

Lets say, I have several customer groups, one of them is Government. I want customer to choose at shipping level whether he is a normal cusotmer (= normal shipping, DHL, FEdEx, ..) or if he's a Federal (= Gov-Shipping).

If the customer chooses Gov Shipping he should see different prices - net instead of gross, however, shipping should be always gross.

How can I do that by creating a new shipping method? Any other possibilities to does that?